# Flash on chrome 69 is not enabled by selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, flash, selenium-chromedriver

After google chrome is being updated to version 69, previously written code for enabling the flash using selenium on python is not working. If anyone found out its solution, please help me and the community

```
options = Options()
prefs = {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins": 1,
    "profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player": 1,
    "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player": 1,
    "PluginsAllowedForUrls": "URL"
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: I am also seeing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this argument to chrome_options.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission")
```

In my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-features=EnableEphemeralFlashPermission")

chrome_prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins": 1,
                "profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player": 1,
                "profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player": 1,
                "PluginsAllowedForUrls": "BEST URL EVER"}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",chrome_prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, service_log_path='NUL')
```